# Working with SharePoint 2013 SiteFeed - where &#"%$!! are the replies authors?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm building a SharePoint sitefeed and where I want to retrieve the replies from a Rootpost, it never has the reply author!! (Basic). Here is the code where i retrieve all replies from a rootpost.

**CODE:**

```
 $.ajax({
 url: getUrl() + "/_api/social.feed/post",
 type: "POST",
 data: JSON.stringify({
    'ID': feed.id
 }),
headers: {
    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "X-RequestDigest": obj
},
success: function (data) {
        getReplies(data, feed);
                    },
 error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
              alert("POST error:\n" + xhr.status + "\n" + thrownError);
                    }
                });
```

**RESPONSE:**
[image: Here is the example with an object, the "real" response is a collection]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.. Each reply has the property "AuthorIndex" this is the index of the autor in the SocialThread property "Actors".